My CNN Model Predicts Only One Class - Balanced Data & Loss Not Converging
I’m working on a CNN model for financial time series prediction. Despite balanced data and several tweaks, my model keeps predicting only one class throughout training, no matter what adjustments I make.
Context
I’m using a custom 1D CNN with three convolutional layers and max-pooling layers. The goal is to classify data into two classes (up, down) based on time-series features. The dataset is balanced across these classes, so theoretically, the model shouldn’t be biased toward one.
The Problem
Here’s where things get confusing:

Learning Rate Sensitivity : At a learning rate of 0.00001 , the model predicts every sample as class 0 . At 0.001 , it swings to predicting everything as class 1 .
Loss Not Converging : Regardless of the learning rate, the loss is not converging to zero, suggesting that the model isn’t learning the underlying patterns effectively.

What I’ve Tried

Checked Class Distribution : Both in the entire dataset and train-test splits to ensure balance.
Learning Rate Scheduler : Experimented with decaying the learning rate, but it still defaults to predicting one class.

Here’s a link to my Colab notebook where you can check out the code and experiment with it directly.

What does the data represent, i.e. what are the input features and what do up and down mean? It might simply be that there is no underlying pattern in the data that can be used to predict the value.
